# Ingresar archivo .txt como entrada

Tags: c, archivo, formato, matriz

intento leer un archivo .txt con el nombre ingresado por el usuario, con el .txt incluido, de manera de que si es el formato incorrecto se lo diga al usuario "Formato de archivo incorrecto" y volver a mostrar la opciones anteriores. Si el archivo no existe le dice al usuario "archivo no existente". Tampoco se me ocurre como hacer los if que mencione anteriormente.

El código me compila, por lo cual no encuentro la razón exacta del fallo, el programa se cierra al ejecutar.
Gracias de antemano

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *name;
int validacion = 0;
while(validacion == 0){
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo matriz P: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    //if para ver si el archivo existe o no
    if(){
    }
    //if para ver si el formato es correcto o no
    else if(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar: [C File Exists](https://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-file-exists/). La forma estándar de hacerlo, es leer el archivo por medio de la función `fopen` y sí el archivo no existe, devuelve `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para validar que el archivo existe esto puede ayudar:

```
int file_exist (char *filename)
{
  struct stat   buffer;   
  return (stat (filename, &buffer) == 0);
}
```

Lo llamas así:

```
if (file_exist ("myfile.txt"))
{
  printf ("It exists\n");
}
```